# How do I use composition and inheritance together?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

I've a case where an object and a collection of objects behave similarly. So to represent the object I've a class:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo();
protected:
    int x;
};
```

And to represent the collection of objects, I've another class:

```
class Collection: public A {
    void foo(); //override base class function
private:
    vector<A*> aList;
}
```

This is fine, but the issue is that Collection class will have a copy of A::x which I don't need. I don't want class Collection to inherit the data members. How do I achieve this?

Note: I can't edit "class A" because it is from a library.
Correction: I can't change the interface of A. A is being used in rest of the code. I can modify the implementation. I can change A::anyFunction() to virtual if it is already not virtual. I can change a private member to protected.

Comment: `Collection::x` and `A::x` is the same `x`.

Comment: I understand that. But I don't want that data member in Collection class.

Comment: Can you edit the functions that expect a polymorphic `A`?

Comment: BTW, was `A` designed to be inherited from?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/1

Comment: @StoryTeller: A was not designed to be inherited.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I can't change the interface of existing class A because it is being used in rest of the code. But I can make other changes to A. For example I can make a function virtual. I can make a private member protected.

Comment: @Galik: Thanks for the pointer. The Composite design pattern should work. In my case the "leaf" is already existing.

Comment: @PramodT: The code which you have shown already resembles `Composite Design Pattern`.

Comment: If it wasn't designed for inhritence, strange it has a virtual function. Unless of course it uses a non-virtual interface, in which case you live with `A::x`, since it's probably vital.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface:

```
class AInterface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

and then

```
class A : public AInterface {
     /*...*/
};

class Collection : public AInterface {
     /*...*/
};
```

If you cant edit `A` you could still use the interface, by writing a wrapper:

```
class AWrapper : public AInterface {
    void foo() { a.foo(); }
private:
    A a;
};
```